# What is the best way to apply a default set of values on an array in redux, but only on initial load?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Our users select one (or more) "solutions" from our site. After that, we show them a list of companies that deliver said solutions. Based on the location of the user and some other variables, we apply a default selection on this list.

We have (among others) `getCompanies` and `getCompanyContainers`.

`getCompanies` returns an array of all companies, and `getCompanyContainers` wraps these companies in a container like this:

```
{
  selected: _.includes(selectedCompanyIds, c.id)
  company: c
}
```

My first try was to check if `selectedCompanyIds` is empty. If it is, apply the algorithm. If not, apply the selection of the user. But if the user deselects all companies, the default algorithm is applied again. I want the algorithm to only be applied on the initial page load.

What would be the best way to do this, while still implementing it in a redux-friendly manner?

Comment: Please... If anybody needs more info, code, whatever, please let me know. This is my first redux-based question, and I'm not sure any code is needed for this particular question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to set initial values to a reducer is actually in your `reducer.js` file where you have your reducer `function(initialState = [ ... ], action) { ... }`. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Is it possible to change these default values depending on variables set by the user later in the app?

Comment: @JeffHuijsmans technically, you would not change the default values, but dispatch an action and the reducer would create a new state with new "default" values.

Comment: That sounds good and robust, awesome! We decided to implement this logic in the backend, as this logic shouldn't be exposed to a malicious user. This question still applies to some other logic in our system, so your answer is not in vain. Thanks!